# How to allow page break inside a float environment?

Tags: floats

I'm using new float enviroment to show some examples in my document. This  enviroment contains `tcolorbox` which provides a gray background. The main text in the enviroment is a mixture of plain text and code blocks (in `lstlisting` env). Each float should have it's own caption and label.

In style file:

```
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[name={Example}]{suppfigure}
```

In the main document:

```
\begin{suppfigure}[!h]
\caption{Some code example}\label{suppfigure1}
\begin{tcolorbox}[arc=0mm, left=1pt, right = 1pt, boxrule=0mm,colback = {shadow-gray}] 

Text

\begin{lstlisting} 
int i = 0; 
\end{lstlisting}

Some more text

\begin{lstlisting} 
String.Format("{0,10:0.0}", -123.4567);  
\end{lstlisting}

\end{tcolorbox} 
\end{suppfigure}
```

How can I allow page break inside the suppfigure to extend my example to multiple pages?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://goo.gl/z69vm) Your post was migrated here from [so]. Please register on this site, too, and make sure that both accounts are associated with each other (by using the same OpenID), otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question.

Answer (score 4):

Floats cannot be broken across pages—they will continue to float until they fit a page or the document ends, whichever comes first. It appears (from usage of `!h`, which is [not recommended](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/21344), by the way) that you're trying to absolutely position this float anyway.

So my recommendation is to use the [`capt-of` package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/capt-of) to place a caption on a non-floating element, since `tcolorbox`es *can* be broken across page boundaries through the use of the `breakable` library.

Since you did not provide a complete MWE, I have made some assumptions about your document in the following code sample.

### Code

```
\documentclass{book} 
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for dummy text to extend over a page break
\usepackage[breakable]{tcolorbox} % load with breakable library
\usepackage{newfloat}
\DeclareFloatingEnvironment[name={Example}]{suppfigure}
\usepackage{capt-of} % captions for non-floating elements

\begin{document}

\captionof{suppfigure}{Some code example}\label{suppfigure1} % place the caption
\begin{tcolorbox}[%
  breakable, % make the box breakable
  arc=0mm, 
  left=1pt, right = 1pt, 
  boxrule=0mm,
  colback = {gray}, % since shadow-gray was not defined
] 

Text

\begin{lstlisting} 
int i = 0; 
\end{lstlisting}

\lipsum % to extend over a page break

\begin{lstlisting} 
String.Format("{0,10:0.0}", -123.4567);  
\end{lstlisting}

\end{tcolorbox}

Referring to Example~\ref{suppfigure1} works as expected.

\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

[image]